# Closed local variable not as expected in anonymous Action

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have the code below where I am trying to call an anonymous `Action<>` with a closure capturing a local variable.

**EDIT: Original Question (simplified, but functional)**

```
public class B
{
    void MyMethod(A instanceA)
    {
        var someRefType = new RefType();
        someRefType.DoSomething();
        someRefType.DoSomethingLater(a => instanceA.ModifyRefType(someRefType));
    }
}

public class A
{
    private Action<object> _action;

    public void ModifyRefType(Action<object> action)
    {
        this._action = action;
    }

    public void DoModify(object configuration)
    {
        this._action?.Invoke(configuration);
    }
}
```

In my understanding, the closure should capture the local variable such that each call to `MyMethod()` would close on a different instance of `someRefType`. However, when I call `MyMethod()` multiple times and afterward call the anonymous `Action` provided in `DoSomethingLater()`, all of the calls to `ModifyRefType()` use the same instance (the instance created in the last call to `MyMethod()`).

What am I missing here? And what is the best way to close around `someRefType` such that each action get's the proper instance?

EDIT: As @dasblinkenlight and @EricLippert suspected, this was not an issue with closing around `someRefType`. The issue was closing around (in this terrible example) `this`. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Please provide a minimal verifiable self-contained example. It's not possible to answer this question with a pseudocide-ish method that you provided.

Comment: Read @EricLippert 's blog about why the initial implementation of closures clashed with the then current scope of a loop variable: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/.  You are likely running into the same (well, similar) issue.

Comment: As dasblinkenlight says, without a small program that reproduces the issue, it is impossible to say what is going on here. Your description of the by-design closure semantics is correct, and therefore either your program does not do what you say it does, or the compiler has a bug. If your program does not do what you say it does, we cannot tell you where your thought process has gone wrong without the program. If the compiler has a bug, the compiler team will need a repro. Either way, we can't help you without a reproducer.

Comment: I note also that you are closing over both `someRefType` and `this`.  Are you sure you're not seeing `this` re-used in each closure, and not `someRefType` ?

Comment: I apologize for the vague code snippet - I was expecting this to be a mis-understanding of closures rather than a separate issue. I will update the question with a better code sample. Thanks!

Comment: If you have an *answer*, put it in the *answer* box below and post it as that. Don't edit it into the box where *questions* are meant to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, this ended up not being a closure scope issues. Below is some simplified code with a "solution".

```
public class B
{
    void MyMethod()
    {
        var instanceA = new A();
        var someRefType = new RefType();
        someRefType.DoSomething();
        someRefType.DoSomethingLater(a => instanceA.ModifyRefType(someRefType));
    }
}

public class A
{
    private Action<object> _action;

    public void ModifyRefType(Action<object> action)
    {
        this._action = action;
    }

    public void DoModify(object configuration)
    {
        this._action?.Invoke(configuration);
    }
}
```

Summary: the same `instanceA` was (accidentally) being used for each call of `instanceA.ModifyRefType()` which meant that action was using the same closure which was closing around both `someRefType` and `instanceA`.

Thank you for the help!